# Check if IndexedDB objectStore already contains key

Tags: google-chrome, indexeddb

Adding an object to an IndexedDB objectStore will fail if the key already exists. How can I check for the existence of an object with a given key – preferably synchronously (no reason for another layer of callbacks) and without pulling the object.

I know how to do get requests asynchronously via transactions, but it seems a bit of an ordeal to go through every time I want to add an object.

*note* Solution only has to work in Chrome (if that helps)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So far none of the browsers have the sync API implemented so you're going to have to do it async. An `objectStore` exposes a `get` method which you provide it with a key and it'll return you the object (or null) that matches the key.

There's a really good tutorial on MDN that covers using IDB, and [getting a record](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB/Using_IndexedDB#Getting_data_from_the_database) is covered too, but the inlined code is:

```
db.transaction("customers").objectStore("customers").get("444-44-4444").onsuccess = function(event) {
  alert("Name for SSN 444-44-4444 is " + event.target.result.name);
};
```

If you don't want retrieve the record then you can always used the `count` method on an index as explained [here in the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/#widl-IDBIndex-count-IDBRequest-any-key). Based on the result of that you can either use `add` or `put` to modify the record, it'll save extracting the record if you don't need to.

Comment: Ideally I wouldn't pull out and initialize a record (some of the objects have a lot of deeply-nested data). Looking for something akin to SQL's EXISTS. I know indexedDB isn't SQL-based, but other key-value stores like Redis support checking the existence of a key

Comment: @Chris - nah there's no method like that, I've added another alternative to working it out if you don't want to hydrate the object

Comment: Well that answers it, though not the way I'd hoped haha. Thank you!

Comment: Some options: 1. Do a count that is restricted with IDBKeyRange.only(id), which avoids deserialization. 2. Use openKeyCursor with IDBKeyRange.only(id) which also avoids deserialization. 3. Use onerror in addition to onsuccess. onerror is fired when store.add fails with your key set (there is a prop defined in your object that corresponds to the store's key that you tried to insert). This way you do not need to do a pre-insert count check (your logic reacts to store.add instead of preempting it).

Answer (score 18):

The best way to check existence of a key is objectStore.count(key). Which is async.

In your case, the best option is openCursor of your key. If exists, cursor will come up.

```
var req = objectStore.openCursor(key);
req.onsuccess = function(e) {
  var cursor = e.target.result; 
  if (cursor) { // key already exist
     cursor.update(obj);
  } else { // key not exist
     objectStore.add(obj)
  }
};
```

Comment: Yeah this seems to be the closest thing to what I want. Pile on the promises!

Comment: @Kyaw Tun Should it be var cursor = e.target.result instead of e.target.target?

Comment: Went ahead and edited `e.target.target` to `e.target.result`.

Comment: @Kyan Tun - you are my hero!!

Comment: you need replace `if (cursor)` to `if (cursor !== undefined)`, because row can contain null value

Comment: the objectStoreon.add with firefox I have the error "A mutation operation was attempted in a READ_ONLY transaction." That makes sense. How to deal with that ?

Answer (score 9):

A bit late for an answer, but possible it helps others. I still stumbled -as i guess- over the same problem, but it's very simple:

If you want to INSERT or UPDATE records you use `objectStore.put(object)` [(help)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore/put)
If you only want to INSERT records you use `objectStore.add(object)` [(help)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore/add)

So if you use `add(object)`, and a record key still exists in DB, it will not overwritten and fires error 0 "ConstraintError: Key already exists in the object store".
If you use `put(object)`, it will be overwritten.

Comment: Hey @Lutz. Do you happen to know how `add` behaves when you have passed in an array as the `keyPath` value? Like this:

```js
db.createObjectStore('users', { keyPath: ['email', 'password']  });
```

I have tried the above but it doesn't fire the ConstraintError as expect. It is adding with differing emails but same password.

Comment: This is exactly what I came here for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The question is why do you want to know this? Maybe you should use another approach?

You can use auto increment, this way you don't need to check if a key exists, you will always get a unique one.

You can also use the put method instead of the add method. With the put the data will be updated if the key exists and if the key doesn't exist the data is added.

Everything depends on the reason why you want to check if something exists.

Comment: Because I'm building an application that, on install, loaded JSON in as demo data. In testing – and in some cases in the wild – the installation callback will fire multiple times so the demo data actually already exists (as indexedDB isn't wiped).

Comment: So in that case you could use the put method. Existing data will be overwritten and new data will be added

Comment: Okay that works in this very specific case, but that isn't the same as checking for existence. That is just forcing data into the DB. There are other cases where I can imagine someone wanting to check for a record's existence without pulling out the data or force updating it.

Comment: I can imagine that, but less on the key it self. I think you will do this more on an index (for example check if a name exist) than for a key. When you check an index, you can make use of the getKey method to only retrieve the key in that case. Or as Kyaw mentioned, use the count method. Either way you can only do it async.